# Javascript in Wordpress - Problem getting a datepicker to run - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm struggling to get a simple bit of Javascript running inside wordpress. The code is taken from an example on the site https://www.daterangepicker.com/ and it's this:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
</script>
```

I know about the noConflict mode necessary when inside Wordpress so I have been trying this:

```
<script>
(function($) {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

That's worked for me before but not in this case. When the page loads the console shows "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: jQuery probably isn't loaded at the time of execution. Try moving your script to right before the closing body tag `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but maybe try replacing the `$` by `jQuery` it worked for me sometimes.

check this : https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/

Also try adding the script using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/

Comment: Thanks for the link,  i'd not see that description before and it helped.